# Add a view at the end of scrolling webview Android

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I want to add a custom view at the end of scroll of webview, so when user reach end of the webview, he can see the custom view.
How to reach that in Android?

```html
  <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fillViewport="true">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <com.app.util.CustomView
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

I tried putting the custom view at bottom and both inside scrollview but didn't work well, there is a big white space area between webview and my custom view

[image]

**EDIT**

I tried Nested scroll but still not working, for this url "https://vimeo.com/171614342#embed" it looks like that

[image]
I can't see page footer or comments section.
here is the code for nested scroll

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: It will be fine if you add any related snippets of what have you tried. It might help stackoverflow users to solve your problems

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: What is the parent layout that holds the scrollview?

Comment: NestedScrollView is the parent, It is a layout for fragment, the activity contains this fragment has FrameLayout which is holding the fragment

Comment: How comes the toolbar at the top? Probably you need to extend your activity to AppCompatActivity

Comment: Because the parent activity has a toolbar, the parent activity layout has LinearLayout with toolbar and the FrameLayout(for fragment webview)

Comment: So you are facing the white space at the bottom of the layout and  webview footer is hidden by custom view?

Comment: something is coming on top of webview which is causing this white space I think, the custom view is displayed normally at bottom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206284/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and-sarah-sami).

Answer (score 3):

Wrap you components inside **NestedScrollView** instead of **ScrollView**. Refer the below snippet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:text="Hello World!" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Also check the screenshot.[image]

Hope you got solution..

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem, I can see white space between webview and custom view like my attached screen shot

Comment: remove your weight property and fillviewport and try?

Comment: I did, I think problem is in webview with height = wrap_content, when I change it to "match_parent" I can see the webview totally but then the custom view is hidden

Comment: can you please copy paste my code in separate activity and check whether it is working? Because there might be some problem in theme you have applied to the activity

Comment: didn't work, I edited my question to include your code and attached screenshot

Comment: I also have this problem. I cannot view my bottom custom view and there is an extra white space. Have you found a solution to this?